# What is the difference between sameAs and alias in Wikidata?

Tags: wikidata, wikipedia, dbpedia

From the descriptions of [sameAs](https://databus.dbpedia.org/dbpedia/wikidata/sameas-all-wikis) and [alias](https://databus.dbpedia.org/dbpedia/wikidata/alias) I don't know how the two relate to each other, and it also provides the [redirects](https://databus.dbpedia.org/dbpedia/wikidata/redirects). And aliases also appear in [properties](https://databus.dbpedia.org/dbpedia/wikidata/properties).